# Pandas series remains the same after appending to it through a function

Tags: python, pandas, append, series

***EDIT:

Although the answer to my question was that the behaviour of pandas does not allow for this kind of operation, I have still marked Henry Ecker's answer as the correct answer as that is the best alternative.***

I am currently having trouble modifying pandas series (and dataframes) when passing them to a function that does the appending via [pandas.Series.append()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.append.html) (the problem is the same with [pandas.concat()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)).
It seems that the original series is not changed after the function has finished executing.

See the code below for an example:

```
import pandas as pd


def main():
    series1 = pd.Series(range(5))
    series2 = pd.Series(range(5, 10))

    print(f'series1 before append_series():\n{series1}\n')
    append_series(series1, series2)
    print(f'series1 after append_series():\n{series1}')


def append_series(ser1, ser2):
    ser1 = ser1.append(ser2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

(note that PyCharm does highlight that `ser1`'s value is not used because it is considered local)

The result of running the code is:

```
series1 before append_series():
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
dtype: int64

series1 after append_series():
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
dtype: int64
```

Where I would expect:

```
series1 before append_series():
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
dtype: int64

series1 after append_series():
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
0    5
1    6
2    7
3    8
4    9
dtype: int64
```

Running that snippet of code shows that `series1` is not changed after the execution of `append_series()`.
I have tried running `id()` on `series1` while in `main()` and on `ser1` while in `append_series()` and both return the same id which I believe means that they do both refer to the same object in memory.
Although I could just use `.append()` inside of `main()` here or define the series as global variables and not have to pass them along, I have encountered the problem in another more complex project which is why I would like to know why this behaviour happens.

My question is therefore, why doesn't the original `series1` get modified after the execution of the function? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: your function doesn't return anything,  so it shouldn't change anything.  are you expecting to pass by reference and use side effects?  all computer science teachings show this is a bad programming paradigm

Comment: I am expecting to be able to modify `series1` inside of `append_series()` and be able to use that modification outside of the function.
As Henry Ecker has mentioned, it would be possible to return the result of `series1.append(series2)` but I am wondering if it is possible to not have to do that.

Comment: The answer to that question is no. All combine type operations of `pandas` dataframes return a new instance. You _must_ assign the result to a new variable. There are no _inplace_ operations for this type of modification.

Comment: Thank you for the quick replies.  
I will try to see how I can go around that in my other project then.  
Cheers!

Comment: when you analyse many of the major system outages and cyber attacks on insecure code at the core is unmanaged shared memory and overflows. i.e the assembler / C malloc model. modern languages protect you against this by strict scoping - breaking this model will almost certainly lead to really nasty bugs and code then will cause many cyber security issues .   out is possible but not a good idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ser1 = ser1.append(ser2)` only changes the *local* variable in the function `append_series`.

`return` from the function instead and assign back to  the `series1` variable in `main`:

```
import pandas as pd


def main():
    series1 = pd.Series(range(5))
    series2 = pd.Series(range(5, 10))

    print(f'series1 before append_series():\n{series1}\n')
    series1 = append_series(series1, series2)
    print(f'series1 after append_series():\n{series1}')


def append_series(ser1, ser2):
    ser1 = ser1.append(ser2)
    return ser1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
series1 before append_series():
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
dtype: int64

series1 after append_series():
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
0    5
1    6
2    7
3    8
4    9
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

you just have to use "return"

```
import pandas as pd


def main():
    series1 = pd.Series(range(5))
    series2 = pd.Series(range(5, 10))

    print(f'series1 before append_series():\n{series1}\n')
    append_series(series1, series2)
    print(f'series1 after append_series():\n{series1}')


def append_series(ser1, ser2):
    ser1 = ser1.append(ser2)
    return ser1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```